# How to make tooltip like button using iphone development language

Tags: ios, iphone, annotations, retina-display, psd

Is that possible to make buttons with rectangle corners like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mayy94s0bo2pp2/tab_example.png?dl=0 in iPhone development without using images?

Comment: Yes. Use CoreGraphics to draw your own background shape using a CGPath.

Comment: Making gradient based buttons with corner radius also possible? like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/01le0oajbye58yk/btn_inviteADealer.png?dl=0 I'm CSS developer. Where can I see what is possible using iphone development languages?